# Нужна подсказка

Tags: орфография

Около 31% интернет-пользователей активно используе(ю)т эту программу.

Добрый день! Очень нужна подсказка!  Какое число использовать и почему?

Answer (score 3):

У Розенталя:  **При составных числительных, оканчивающихся на один, сказуемое, как правило, ставится в форме единственного числа**, например: Двадцать один делегат прибыл на совещание; ...было подано сразу тридцать одно заявление (Шолохов). **Форма множественного числа данной конструкции может быть обусловлена контекстом,** например: Двадцать один делегат встретились за круглым столом (сказуемое-глагол встретились указывает на взаимное действие, которое выражается формой множественного числа); Двадцать один ящик с посудой, которые были доставлены на базу, попали туда по ошибке (влияние придаточного предложения с союзным словом которые в форме множественного числа); За все уплачено 231 рубль (при формальной роли подлежащего счетный оборот имеет значение обстоятельства меры в страдательной конструкции); Двадцать один студент не явились на экзамен (эмоционально окрашенный разговорный вариант, подчеркивающий количество отсутствовавших).

Для тех, кому интересна тема - вот анализ примеров из Национального корпуса (именно со словом процент) и сравнение выводов с данными справочников. link text

Основной вывод: 
**В предложениях с подлежащим, выраженным счетным оборотом и включающим слово проценты,** **сказуемое преимущественно стоит во множественном числе.** Таким образом, предпочтительным оказывается согласование по смыслу.

Так что Fuchoin Kazuki права.

Answer (score 2):

Просится множественное число: 31% пользователей активно используют..." Все-таки речь о пользователях, а не о проценте.

Answer (score 0):

> При составных числительных, оканчивающихся на один...

Но в нашем случае "около тридцати одного", а не "тридцать один" и к тому же, действительно

> Все-таки речь о пользователях, а не о проценте.

Значит, всё-таки множественное число.